# Wicket add method after the button click

Tags: java, wicket

I have the question, how to "reload" add method after the button click? for example:

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
DataView dataView = new DataView("listview", new ListDataProvider(list)) {
    public void populateItem(final Item item) {
            final DBUser user = (DBUser) item.getModelObject();
            item.add(new Label("id", String.valueOf(user.getid())));
     }
};
final Load load = new Load(dataView);
    Form<?> form2 = new Form<Void>("form2") {
        @Override
        protected void onSubmit() {

            load.tick();
        }
};
add(dataView);
```

Now the load class:

```
public class Load {
private DataView dataView;

public Load(DataView dataView)
{
    this.dataView = dataView;
}

public DataView tick()
{
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();//getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    Query query = session.createQuery(
            "from DBUser");
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    for (Iterator it=query.iterate();it.hasNext();) {
        DBUser row = (DBUser) it.next();
        DBUser dbuser = new DBUser(row.getid());
        list.add(dbuser);
    }

    dataView = new DataView("listview", new ListDataProvider(list)) {
        public void populateItem(final Item item) {
            final DBUser user = (DBUser) item.getModelObject();
            item.add(new Label("id", String.valueOf(user.getid())));
        }
    };
    session.close();
    return dataView;
}
```

}

Right now add(line) method was called just once, how to call it after every button click?

here is my .html

```
<table frame="below" border=1>
    <tr wicket:id="listview">
         <td align="center" width="40"><span wicket:id="id"></span></td>
     </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: Why would it be called more than once? It is just sitting in the middle of the your code. Is it in a method that should be called? This is obviously not valid Java syntax. Please provide more of your code.

Comment: What are you trying to archive? String is not something you can add to a Component? That code does not make any sense at all

Comment: and on each click, you want to reload?

Comment: right, cause i want to make some changes before the click

Comment: It's not reloading because the only `DataView` you ever add to your page is the one you create in the first code snippet, the one created on the empty `ArrayList`. The one you create in `tick()` is never used for anything - the code doesn't continue past the end of the `onSubmit()` method.

Comment: Your whole approach shows you've missed the point of Wicket entirely. You shouldn't need to replace components on a page with ones bound to new data. Wicket allows you to set up components that refresh their data automatically by connecting them with `Models`. A discussion of what they are and how to apply them in your case is beyond the scope of an SO answer though, I suggest you reread the tutorials or Wicket in Action.

Comment: You also seem confused by how fields in Java work. When you do `load = new Load(dataView);`, and then in a method of `Load` change the value of its `dataView` field, this won't change the value of the local variable this field was originally populated from.

Comment: @millimoose , the point is that i can't get access to my **dataView** that i've created in the first code snippet from my onSubmit method, that's why i've tried to create Load class, to get access. Is there a way to do that? without creating a class?

Comment: @fen1ksss You should only ever need to create one `DataView`; you can then store it as a *field* on the page. This would be the idiomatic way of working with Wicket. The `Load` class shouldn't exist - the code in it should be in the `IDataProvider` that the `DataView` uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you could reload your DataView in such a way:

```
Form<?> form2 = new Form<Void>("form2") {

    @Override
    protected void onSubmit() {
        StartPage.this.replace( load.tick() );
        // or you can use 
        // StartPage.this.addOrReplace( load.tick() ) 
        // instead
    }
};
```

But your code also needs serious refactoring! As for me I would write it like so to improve readability:

```
final Load load = new Load();

Form<?> form2 = new Form<Void>("form2") {
    @Override
    protected void onSubmit() {
        StartPage.this.replace( createDataView( load.tick() ) );
    }
};
add(form2);

add( createDataView( new ArrayList() ) );
```

Implementation of the createDataView(list) method:

```
private DataView createDataView(List list) {
    return new DataView("listview", new ListDataProvider(list)) {
        public void populateItem(final Item item) {
            final DBUser user = (DBUser) item.getModelObject();
            item.add(new Label("id", String.valueOf(user.getid())));
        }
    };
}
```

Implementation of the Load class:

```
public class Load {

    public List tick() {
        List result = new ArrayList();
        // ...
        // populate list from database
        // ...
        return result;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: the main point was to add **StartPage.this.replace( load.tick() );**